# NullInjectorError: No provider for TreeHelperPipe

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular5, angular-pipe

I need some help please.
I don't understand why this test does not work.
I use a @pipe.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TreeHelperPipe } from 'app/shared/components/material-tree/tree-helper.pipe';

describe('Tree helper', () => {
  let pipe: TreeHelperPipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    pipe = new TreeHelperPipe();
  });

  describe('truncateString', () => {
    it(
      `should have string truncate and replace some part by dots`,
      inject([TreeHelperPipe], (_TreeHelperPipe: any) => {
        const item =
          'http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/ged-sharepoint/1.1';

        const expectedItem =
          'http://namespace-example.fr/s...e/technique/version/ged-sharepoint/1.1';

        expect(() => {
          _TreeHelperPipe.transform(item, 60, '...').toBe(expectedItem);
        });
      })
    );
  });
});
```

> Error: StaticInjectorError[TreeHelperPipe]:     NullInjectorError: No
>   provider for TreeHelperPipe!

What's wrong with my test ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
inject([TreeHelperPipe], (_TreeHelperPipe: any) => {
```

You're trying to inject a Pipe, but you didn't create any module before that. That's why Angular doesn't find the pipe you're trying to inject.

That said, here you do not need a module and you can just create an instance as you've done here:

```
pipe = new TreeHelperPipe();
```

Then make your assertions by calling `pipe.transform(your, arguments, here)` (and do not forget to remove the line with `inject`).

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks Maxime !